How to set Thunar for file selection dialogs in gnome?
I'm using Fedora 40 with Wayland & Gnome 46. While I like almost everything about gnome with some heavy tweaking, I passionately hate nautilus. It is really bad for folders with many items, it is buggy and sluggish. I love Thunar and I've set it as my default file manager using the following command:
xdg-mime default thunar.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

Even though it actually uses Thunar as my file manager, nautilus is still being used for file/folder selection, my question is, how do I set thunar for that?
I've came across some workarounds such as removing nautilus and replacing its executable with thunar's; using xdg-desktop-portal-gtk along with GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 and I dislike both of these. Would appreciate a more robust and potentially non-system-breaking one, thanks.
